# Samba Printer Stops Working After Awhile

Tags: printing

I have an Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS system which is a server on my private network and I have a couple of Windows clients. The server has two printers attached which are older HP printers (Laserjet 6L on a parallel port, and a Laserjet 1018 on USB). I set up the printers to use on the network with Windows clients via samba. In my Samba config, I just have

```
load printers = yes
cups options = raw
```

I can see the printers fine from Windows clients and print. However, every few days printing to both of these printers stops working. I've tried restarting the CUPS service as well as the samba service to get them going again but it doesn't work. The only solution I've found is to reboot the Ubuntu server, then all of the jobs I had sent that didn't print will start printing immediately after the reboot completes.

Anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: On the server, `service cups status` will show the current status of the print spooler, and `journalctl --since="- 10 minutes"` will show system logs for the last 10 (adjust to include time of failure) minutes

Comment: @waltinator thank you. I'll check those on the next failure.

Comment: When you get results, remember to Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1146975/edit ) your question to add the results (don't put them in comments, or in links, or in screenshots)